# How to get text from an array in javascript and append it to a texarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I am trying to get a file path from an array that changes dynamically and is stored inside the value c. When I click the button that activates it however it returns the web address the the number the file is in the array exp. I want www.anon-curb.com/swfs/exampleflash.swf but it gives me www.anon-curb.com/swfs/464 ;the 464 being the order it is in the array.

HTML

```
<div class="share_con">
                <button id="share">Get a link!</button>
                <textarea id="link"></textarea>
            </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var c = sessionStorage.getItem('order');
    sessionStorage.setItem('order', c);
    var flashcon, test, temp;

    share = document.getElementById('share');
    link = document.getElementById('link');

    function init() {

        share.onclick = function () {
            console.log('Event: share button clicked');
            shareshare();
        }

    }

    function shareshare() {
        console.log('Called: shareshare()');
        link.innerHTML = 'www.anon-curb.com/' + c;
    }

    // What displays the actual flash and title for the flash
    function displayFiles() {
        console.log('Called: displayFiles()');
        test = paths[c].substring(paths[c].lastIndexOf('.') + 1, paths[c].length);
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = displaytext[c];

        flashcon.innerHTML =
            '<object id="flashcontent" data="' + paths[c] + '">' +
            '<param name="movie" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">' +
            '</object>';
    }
    window.addEventListener ?
        window.addEventListener('load', init, false) :
        window.attachEvent('onload', init);
});
```

All variables are created and called correctly my only problem is I don't know how to get the actual text contained in the array instead of the order it comes in.

Comment: What is your array referenceable as? Use bracket notation `arr[c]`

Comment: I gave more of my JavaScript code that I thought would help

Comment: Can you give us a debug of your `sessionStorage`?

Comment: You probably want to do `link.innerHTML = 'www.anon-curb.com/' + paths[c];` instead of `link.innerHTML = 'www.anon-curb.com/' + c;`. You have not provided the code where you define `paths`, but seeing how you use it, I think that is what you need?

Comment: Omg... dude I just posted that as my answer and the page didn't update when I did it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some fiddling and I had the though "I'm so dumb!!! Why don't I just use the number the c is to call the text within the array?" So thats what I did!

```
function shareshare() {
        var l = paths[c];
        console.log('Called: shareshare()');
        link.innerHTML = 'www.anon-curb.com/' + l;
    }
```

By the way I have noooo idea why I didn't think of this instantly I feel blahhhh

Comment: Yep, that is what I suggested in comments 2 minutes before you posted this.

Comment: Yaaa I know but I didn't update the page bc I was scrolled down when I was choding it so I didn't see that

Comment: no problem. Most important is that you got a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking through your code I noticed some issues:

1. Textareas use `innerText`, not `innerHTML`:

   This is a simple fix, just switch the two in `shareshare`

   ```
   function shareshare() {
     console.log('Called: shareshare()');
     link.innerText = 'www.anon-curb.com/' + c;
   }
   ```

Also take note of your solution:

```
function shareshare() {
    var l = paths[c];
    console.log('Called: shareshare()');
    link.innerHTML = 'www.anon-curb.com/' + l;
}
```

Hope I could be somewhat helpful (even though you've figured it out)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but innerHTML worked just fine :D

Comment: Huh. In my version of Chrome (51) it doesn't work, and from what I've read from the specifications, `innerText` is the method to use. TIL, guess!